# Adding StackPanel in StackPanel Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a layout which is made on runtime.

layout will be divided into 2, 3, 4, ...

For example, There is a Big Box with 1 image.

If I drag and drop a image, it will be divided into two.

Like `A => A | B or B | A`

and If I drag&drop another image, it will be

```
            A |          | B
A | B =>    --| B  or  A | --
            C |          | C
```

simple hint will be great.

Comment: you could solve it in multiple ways. one approach could be to use say a grid with 2 Row's and "n" columns(you can get such a `Grid` by using [@Rachel's WPF Grid Helper](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)). Now iterate through the elements and position them accordingly as per your requirement. You got `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` to deal with end elements that you want stretched across multiple Grid cells

Comment: So you didn't even check answers :(

Comment: I have used other way and thanks for the reply but it wasn't helpful to me so I have not checked answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is so far simple. Lets make this clear. First of all the root stack panel let's say it is A,will be of `Orientation="Horizontal"` Something like as follows:

```
StackPanel A = new StackPanel();
A.Width = 300;
A.Height = 200;
A.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
A.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

Now once we have A,we know it's root,whenever we add something to it ,it will place that on right,which is ofcourse the way you want A | B or more A | B | C.
Now when you drag and drop an Image check -

The co-ordinates of the image to detect on which parent layout it's hovering,then check if it's a StackPanel(`if(theLayout is StackPanel)`)

Now check what is the orientation of the stackpanel. `[PseudoCode]`-

```
if(Horizontal)
{
     //Create a stackpanel with Vertical Orientation and place the image inside it
     //stackpanel_with_v_orientation.Children.Add(yourImage)
     //then add this stackpanel to theLayout like theLayout.Children.Add(stackpanel_with_v_orientation);
}
else
{
    //its over some sub panels,which are ofcourse with vertical 
    //orientation.just add this up.
}
```

Something like this!Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: makes great sense.  and add the stackpanel to, for example, your Grid x:named "maingrid" as in maingrid.Children.Add(A);

Answer (score 0):

You could use DockPanel or WrapPanel. And if that is not enough, you could implement your own [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) logic specifying how the items should be arranged. Anyway take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms754152.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

At the end you want a docking control like this: http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

Wow, you certainly like a challenge! For that you will need to create quite a complicated custom `Panel` implementation. In this `Panel`, you will have access to the children (item) in the `Panel` and so you *should* be able to achieve your requirements with some careful thinking. I can provide you with some links to some tutorials on the subject, but after that, you're pretty much on your own.

Please view the articles in these links for help:

[How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html)

[Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF)

Comment: Sorry,it's nothing that much complicated.There is always a way to think simple. :)

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim, this is a valid solution. It *may* not be the simplest, but the user can still achieve his goal using this method. He did not mention anything about requiring the simplest method.